# Do not go to a new page Vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm new in vue js. And my task is to take data from api, make pagination and when clicking on any post so that a new page opens with more detailed information about the post. I did the pagination, but I can't make the transition. In clicking on the post, the link changes but the transition is not performed.

[Project on GitHub](https://github.com/belichenk0andreyka/Blog)

My main code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(post, index) of paginatedData" class="post">
          <router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: {id: index} }">
          <img src="src/assets/nature.jpg">
          <p class="boldText"> {{ post.title }}</p>
          </router-link>
          <p> {{ post.body }}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>



  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      current: null,
      page: 0,
      posts: [],
      }
    },
    created(){
      this.getData()
    },
    methods: {
    setCurrent: function(id) {
      this.current = id;
    },
    getData() {
      axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`).then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data
      })
    },
  }
  }
</script>
```

My detail post page:

```
<template>
  <div class="post" v-if="detail">
    <img src="src/assets/nature.jpg">
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  module.exports = {
    data: function() {
      return {
        posts: [],
      }
    },
    created: function() {
      var postId = this.$route.params.id
      this.post = this.posts[postId]
    }
  }
</script>
```

My main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

var Detail = require('./Detail.vue')

Vue.use(VueRouter)

var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: 'detail/:id', name: 'detail', component: Detail }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router: router,
})
```

Comment: did you try `:to="'detail/'+id"` ?

Comment: Here is what is written in the link http://localhost:8080/#/detail/detail/detail/detail/undefined

Answer (score 0):

You need a router-view tag. This basically renders the routed component inside the tags.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html

Comment: <li v-for="(post, index) of paginatedData" class="post">
          <router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: {id: index} }">
          <img src="src/assets/nature.jpg">
          <p class="boldText"> {{ post.title }}</p>
          </router-link>
          <p> {{ post.body }}</p>

          <router-view></router-view>

Comment: I added <router-view></router-view> to <li></li> but it did not work

Comment: router view should be somewhere on a root element, e.g. in App.vue. Your Pagination would be a List component and should also be added to your router.
You can take a look inside the example..